# Import text file into SQL Server table using BCP utility by ignoring text qualifier (double quotes)

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using the BCP utility to import data into SQL Server 2014. I am importing a `.dsv` file which is delimited by `~`.

But data in my file also contains text qualifiers (double quotes).

How can I ignore the text qualifiers? I want the data to not have these quotes, just like it does in the flat text file.

- I would like to avoid using a format file because I am using lots flat text files with great variability.
- I also cannot use Bulk Insert because my files are not stored on the server, but a local machine that is connecting via SSMS.

EDIT: my BCP command:

```
bcp test.dbo.Mel_table in C:\Files\Melb_geo.dsv -n -T 
    -S DESKTOP-TDGEOR9\SQLEXPRESS -t"~" -r"\n" -q -e C:\Files\Melb_geo_err.txt
```

Data in `Melb_geo.txt` as below:

```
"Melbourne"~"2013"~"116405"~"2014-05-13"
"Melbourne"~"2014"~"122199"~"2011-11-20"
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: I don't think `bcp` provides any handling of quoted identifers.
Have you tried using SSIS? It will be pretty straightforward importing such data through SSIS packages (you will need Integration Services installed on the machine you run the package on).
Other option can be to bcp the data in a staging table and remove all the double quotes using SQL and then inserting into the main table. That is fair bit of work though.

Comment: thanks @AmitSukralia  Unfortuantely, i don't have the privilege to use SSIS. Trying  to import using bcp to a staging table (as suggested) but it fails to pull data.. Command output below :                                                                 
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1

Comment: All the columns should be character columns to import data in the staging table. Also, I am not an expert in `bcp` but have you tried replacing `-n` with `-c`. Most of the times it is these two parameters along with `-r` when bcp complains about EOF.

Comment: Yes, i have tried -c option too but no joy.

Comment: okay, can you check and confirm what are the row delimiters in your file. Is it CR+LF or something else? Also, please send your bcp query as well.

Comment: Yes, it is CR+LF                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
bcp query :  C:\>bcp test.dbo.Mel_table in C:\Files\Melb_geo.dsv -n -T -S DESKTOP-TDGEOR9\SQLEXPRESS -t"~" -r'\n' -q -e C:\Files\Melb_geo_err.txt                       
      SQL table [Mel_table] structure :                                                          Geography [text] NOT NULL,Year [int] NOT NULL,Population [int] NOT NULL,DATE_CREATED [date] NOT NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173731/discussion-between-amit-sukralia-and-upendrakumarp).